Adding a custom item to a react-google-places-autocomplete?
I was wondering if it's possible to add a custom item into a GooglePlacesAutocomplete? I can't seem to get it to work. Addresses work wonderfully, but I can't add my own item, preferably to be the first item.
Tried a few things such as:
autocompletionRequest={{
                componentRestrictions: { country: 'AU' },
                types: ['(regions)', **'Remote'],**
              }}

I also tried adding 'option', but had no luck. Has anyone ever done this? I need to add a default entry, specifically 'Remote' as I'm building a website which could have remote as a location option.
<GooglePlacesAutocomplete
apiKey="xxx"
fetchDetails={true}
defaultValue={where ? { label: where } : null}
onLoadFailed={(error) => console.error("Google Places Autocomplete load failed", error)}
selectProps={{
placeholder: "Enter suburb for the task...",
sClearable: true,
menuPortalTarget: document.body,
value: where ? { label: where } : null,
onChange: (selectedOption) => {
  if (selectedOption) {
    setWhere(selectedOption.label);
  } else {
    setWhere('');
  }
},
styles: {
  control: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    height: '48px', // Slightly smaller to match NextUI "lg" more closely
    minHeight: '48px',
    borderRadius: '0.375rem', // Matches NextUI's rounded-lg
    borderColor: 'hsl(214, 100%, 50%)', // Primary color similar to NextUI
    boxShadow: 'none',
    '&:hover': {
      borderColor: 'hsl(214, 100%, 50%)',
    },
    '&.is-focused': {
      borderColor: 'hsl(214, 100%, 50%)',
      boxShadow: '0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 111, 238, 0.2)', // Similar to NextUI focus effect
    },
  }),
  singleValue: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    color: 'black',
  }),
  input: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    color: 'black',
  }),
  menu: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    zIndex: 9999,
    borderRadius: '0.375rem',
    boxShadow: '0 4px 6px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1), 0 2px 4px -2px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1)',
  }),
  option: (provided, state) => ({
    ...provided,
    backgroundColor: state.isSelected 
      ? 'hsl(214, 100%, 50%)' 
      : state.isFocused 
        ? 'hsl(214, 100%, 95%)' 
        : 'white',
    color: state.isSelected ? 'white' : 'black',
    ':active': {
      backgroundColor: 'hsl(214, 100%, 50%)',
      color: 'white',
    },
  }),
  dropdownIndicator: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    color: 'hsl(214, 20%, 50%)', // Subtle indicator color
  }),
  clearIndicator: (provided) => ({
    ...provided,
    color: 'hsl(214, 20%, 50%)', // Subtle clear indicator color
  }),
},
}}
autocompletionRequest={{
componentRestrictions: { country: 'AU' },
types: ['(regions)'],
// Add a custom filter to remove train stations and other irrelevant results
strictbounds: true,
}}
/>

